# Write logic on html page with Knockout Data bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout and make editing with already implemented code.
I have write a logic on html page where KO is binded, but is not working.

```
data-bind='visible: ($data.isFellowTypeApplication && ($data.memberTypeId.toUpperCase() != "9F8CF4C5-F067-4A18-A1C0-A2F91CDD803A") && ($data.memberTypeId.toUpperCase() != "D8E6E36A-777F-4344-87FB-E8010C80A88E"))'
```

Does anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or even KO allow writing logic here?

```
            <div class="form-group fellow-publication" data-bind='visible: ($data.isFellowTypeApplication && ($data.memberTypeId.toUpperCase() != "9F8CF4C5-F067-4A18-A1C0-A2F91CDD803A") && ($data.memberTypeId.toUpperCase() != "D8E6E36A-777F-4344-87FB-E8010C80A88E"))'>
                <div class="controls cbCertify col-sm-12">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" name="Checkbox2" data-bind='checked: $data.isLikeToMember' />
                    Should be visible only if above condition gets true.
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: To help you you'd need to edit the question and include all (though minimal amount) of the code needed to reproduce your issue. Please consider using a runnable Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a `ko.computed` variable in your javascript viewmodel that controls whether this item is visible.  Something like:

```
this.isVisible = ko.computed(function() {
        return isFellowTypeApplication && (memberTypeId.toUpperCase() != "9F8CF4C5-F067-4A18-A1C0-A2F91CDD803A") && (memberTypeId.toUpperCase() != "D8E6E36A-777F-4344-87FB-E8010C80A88E");
    }, this);
```

Then you can update your HTML to something like:

```
<div class="form-group fellow-publication" data-bind='visible: $data.isVisible'>
  <div class="controls cbCertify col-sm-12">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" name="Checkbox2" data-bind='checked: $data.isLikeToMember' />
       Should be visible only if above condition gets true.
   </div>
</div>
```

This will also make it easier for you to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The @Kez answer is also worked, But finally the logic on HTML also worked. This is the code I have used.

```
            <div class="form-group fellow-publication" data-bind='visible: ($data.isFellowTypeApplication)'>
                <div class="controls cbCertify col-sm-12" data-bind='visible: $data.memberTypeId.toUpperCase() != "9F8CF4C5-F067-4A18-A1C0-A2F91CDD803A" && $data.memberTypeId.toUpperCase() != "D8E6E36A-777F-4344-87FB-E8010C80A88E"'>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" name="Checkbox2" data-bind='checked: $data.isLikeToMember' />
                    Should be visible only if above condition gets true.
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: always preferred way is to do it in viewModel which makes code manageable & easy to track . cheers